# how do i find out what view or editor is an active workbench page using RCP eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

Many workbench APIs are accessible only from IWorkbenchWindow or IWorkbenchPage.

My Question is 
I am click the toolbar or Button to get which view or editor current working

or

find out the Active workbench page or Active workbench window using RCP eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You get the active `IWorkbenchWindow` using:

```java
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();

IWorkbenchWindow activeWindow = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
```

from the window you can get the active page:

```java
IWorkbenchPage activePage = activeWindow.getActivePage();
```

and from the page you can the active editor (if any):

```java
IEditorPart activeEditor = activePage.getActiveEditor();
```

or the active part (editor or view):

```java
IWorkbenchPart activePart = activePage.getActivePart();
```

If you are in a command handler and have an `ExecutionEvent` object you can also use the `HandlerUtil` class to get these objects from the event.